# select is truncating column names in ij

Tags: derby

the derby doc's say:

```
To start ij with a maximumDisplayWidth of 1000:

java -Dij.maximumDisplayWidth=1000 -jar derbyrun.jar
```

I tried the following:

```
java -Dij.maximumDisplayWidth=1000 -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueJ\Derby\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\lib\derbyrun.jar"
```

and got:

```
Usage:
java -jar derbyrun.jar ij [-p propertiesfile] [sql script]
java -jar derbyrun.jar sysinfo [-cp ...] [-cp help]
java -jar derbyrun.jar dblook [args] (or no arguments for usage)
java -jar derbyrun.jar server [args] (or no arguments for usage)
java -jar derbyrun.jar SignatureChecker [args]
java -jar derbyrun.jar PlanExporter [args]
```

Comment: Where did you find that in the docs? It's missing an argument, as you can see in the error message. You need to add "ij" at the end of your command line.